# jQuery: How to chain css() with delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fid: https://jsfiddle.net/k13sazuz/

How do I chain delay with css rules in jQuery?

```js
$('.two').css('background','blue').delay(11800).css('background','red');
```

```css
.two{
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  background:blue;
}
.ok{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok">hey</div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: [JSFiddle of the example from the duplicated OP](https://jsfiddle.net/k13sazuz/2/)

Comment: Just use `setTimeout()`? [Check it](https://jsfiddle.net/k13sazuz/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$.fn.delayCss=function(Time,Name,Value){
var This=this;
setTimeout(function(){
This.css(Name,Value);
},Time);
return this;
};
$('.two').delayCss(1000,'background','red');
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of *how* this works as well